# PyQgis display vertex marker when in editing mode

Tags: pyqgis, editing, vertices, markers

Documentation says when issue the following command on a vector layer (polygon), the vertex marker will be displayed in editing mode:

```
layer.startEditing()
```

But it is not displaying the vertex markers.

I found that there is a static drawVertexMarker method on QgsVectorLayer class, but do I have to manually call it to draw a marker on each vertex? Also, if I am moving vertex in editing mode, do I have to constantly re-draw all vertices?

Additionally, there is the editBuffer() property that returns the QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer reference, is it possible to display that buffer layer in editing mode for visual aid?

Comment: @German Carrillo, thanks, that's it. Calling the 'canvas.refresh()' does it. How to flag your comment as the answer.

Comment: @Germán Carrillo, please post your comment as an answer

Comment: Just posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're just missing a call to

```
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

after you call `startEditing()` from the layer object. Doing so you can visualize vertex markers from your layer features.